# Prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \sinh(x)/x =1$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, hyperbolic-functions

> Prove that $ \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sinh x}{x} =1.$

I am having some trouble proving this without derivative. Some help would be much appreciate!

Comment: Use the taylor series expansion for the exponential at zero and plug it into the formula for Sinh

Comment: I don't know if editing this would change the intent of this question... but, $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sinh x}{x} \neq 0$

Comment: If you did do L'Hopital correctly you should get that the derivative of the top is $=\frac{1}{2}(e^x-e^{-x})'=\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})$ and the derivative of the bottom is $1$, so the new limit is $\frac{2}{2}$

Comment: Why use L'Hopital, when it is exactly the definition of the derivative at $x=0$ of $\sinh x$? @Squirtle

Comment: I agree completely; I was more concerned that user157308 made a computational error as per a previous statement in the question, "I am having trouble proving this without using L'Hopital" and of course the original title saying that the limit was $0$.  I just assumed somehow they were able to get $0$ doing it the "obvious" way but obviously missing it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No reason to shy away from complex numbers. Let $x = iu$.

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sinh x}{x} &= \lim_{u\to 0} \frac{\sinh (iu)}{iu} \\ &= \lim_{u\to 0} \frac{i\sin (u)}{iu} \\ &= \lim_{u\to 0} \frac{\sin (u)}{u} \\ &=1\end{align}$$

Answer (score 9):

$$\frac{\sinh x}{x}=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2x}=\frac{1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...-\left(1-x+\frac{x^2}{2!}_...\right)}{2x}=\frac{2x+\frac{2x^3}{3!}+..}{2x}=1+\frac{x^2}
{3!}+...$$

Takong $\lim$ on both sides we get $1$
${{{{}}}}$

Comment: `\sin hx` should be `\sinh x`... :)

Comment: It's not clear to me that using the Taylor expansion is "not using the derivative..." :)

Answer (score 7):

Rewrite using known limit for $e$:

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sinh(x)}{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x - 1 + 1 - e^{-x}}{2x} = \frac{1}{2} \lim \frac{e^x - 1}{x} - \frac{1}{2} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{-x}-1}{x}
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2} \lim \frac{e^x - 1}{x} + \frac{1}{2} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x} = 1
$$

Comment: Another to get that: $$\frac{sinh x}{2x} = e^{-x}\frac {e^{2x}-1}{2x}$$ $e^x\to 1$ and the second part is the same as $\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $\displaystyle\sin ⁡x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ and $\displaystyle\sinh ⁡x=\frac{\sin⁡(ix)}{i}$

Answer (score 3):

You could use the squeeze theorem with bounding functions 1 and $e^{|x|}$

Comment: But how would you show that $\frac {\sinh x} x \geq 1$?