# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{1-\cos x}$ without using L'Hospital's Rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Compute without using L'Hospital's Rule $$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{1-\cos x}.$$

I thought of simplifying the limit as shown below.
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{1-\cos x}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{2\sinh^2 x(1+\cos x)}{\sin^2 x(1+\cosh x)}\\
&=\space2\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sinh^2 x}{\sin^2 x}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1+\cos x}{1+\cosh x}
\end{align} But I'm a little stuck as to how to show that
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sinh^2 x}{\sin^2 x}=1$$
so that the original limit is $2$. I can't just use a simple substitution.

**Any** help would be nice.

---

**Edit:** No use of L'Hospital's Rule is allowed. If I were allowed to use that, I would simply do the following:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{1-\cos x} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{\sin x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}{\cos x}=2$$ 
That is literally **trivial**.

Comment: Have you noticed which function's square has its limit sought?

Comment: Write $\dfrac{\sinh x}{\sin x}$ as $\dfrac{\sinh x}{x}\cdot\dfrac{x}{\sin x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide numerator and denominator by $x^2$

And use the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{sinh (x)}{x}= 1$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{sin (x)}{x}=1$

Here you can find the proof of limit of sinh 
[Prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \sinh(x)/x =1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/851856/687026)

Comment: If you know that then you can easily solve your problem

Comment: thanks the proof was interesting. i didn't think of using complex numbers but that's perfectly legal.

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain what my comment meant, we're trying to compute $\lim_{x\to0}\frac12f^2(x)=\frac12\left(\lim_{x\to0}f(x)\right)^2$ with$$f(x):=\frac{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{\frac{e^{x/2}-1}{x/2}-\frac{e^{-x/2}-1}{x/2}}{\frac{\sin\frac{x}{2}}{x/2}}.$$Since for any function $g$ we define $g^\prime(0):=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x/2)-g(0)}{x/2}$ (this is *not* a use of the full-blown L'Hôpital's rule),$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\frac{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{x/2}-1}{x/2}-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-x/2}-1}{x/2}}{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\frac{x}{2}}{x/2}}=\frac{\left.\frac{de^x}{dx}\right|_0-\left.\frac{de^{-x}}{dx}\right|_0}{\left.\frac{d\sin x}{dx}\right|_0}=\frac{1-(-1)}{1}=2.$$Hence$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac12f^2(x)=\frac122^2=2.$$

Answer (score -1):

Directly with the original limit and L'Hospital's Rule:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{1-\cos x}\stackrel{L'H}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{\sin x}\stackrel{L'H}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{\cos x}=2$$

Answer (score -1):

$e^x+e^{-x}-2=\dfrac{(e^x-1)^2}{e^x}$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{1-\cos x}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{(1+\cos x)}{e^x}\left(\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^x-1}{\sin x}\right)^2$$

Finally $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{e^h-1}h=1$

and $\lim_{u\to0}\dfrac{\sin u}u=1$

Comment: @fordjones, Please find the updated post